# How to prevent Beamer from repeatedly expanding macros in \frametitle when frame-breaking

Tags: beamer

The following latex source generates two pdf pages. Page 1 has title "Exercise 1 I" and page 2 "Exercise **2** II".

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\let\Tiny=\tiny
\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{0}
\def\exercise{\refstepcounter{mycounter}Exercise \arabic{mycounter}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
  \frametitle{\exercise}  % this seems expanded in each frame

  ABC

  \framebreak

  DEF
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The resulting page 1 is

```
Exercise 1 I
  ABC
```

and page 2

```
Exercise 2 II  % I want Exercise 1 II
  DEF
```

I want "Exercise 1 II" on page 2 instead. One way is to delete `\refstepcounter{mycounter}` from the `\exercise` macro and to manually do `\refstepcounter` outside. This is nuisance, and I would make mistakes. Would there be a better way?

Comment: My guess is that you cannot prevent it, since on the one hand this is how beamer works and one the other hand this is what one usually wants, e.g. when creating overlays. I suggest to separate incrementing the counter and typesetting the frametitle: Move the `\refstepcounter` command before `\begin{frame}`, then it is executed only once.

Comment: Disappointed, but good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the counter `\beamer@autobreakcount` and do the stepping only if this counter has a less than 2 (it will be normally zero, but it becomes 1 when `allowframebreaks` is issued).

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\let\Tiny=\tiny

\newcounter{mycounter}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\exercise{%
  \ifnum\beamer@autobreakcount<2
    \refstepcounter{mycounter}%
  \fi
  Exercise \themycounter
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{\exercise}  % this seems expanded in each frame

  ABC

  \framebreak

  DEF
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\exercise}

GHI

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

@gernot: Never say never with LaTeX :)

The basic idea is to test if the current page is the first page of a frame and only then to increase the counter.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\let\Tiny=\tiny
\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{0}

\makeatletter
\def\exercise{%
    \ifnum\insertframestartpage=\thepage
        \refstepcounter{mycounter}
    \fi
    Exercise \arabic{mycounter}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
  \frametitle{\exercise}  % this seems expanded in each frame

  ABC

  \framebreak

  DEF
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The `\ifnum\insertframestartpage=\thepage` trick is excellent. I wish I could accept multiple answers.